# Letter spacing seems particularly cramped

Tags: fonts, spacing

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
filecolor=blue,      
urlcolor=blue,
citecolor=blue,
linktoc=page,
}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

{\Large \textbf{Academic Purpose} \par}

The use of perturbation theory in quantum field theory (QFT) has been wildly successful to the point of developing the most rigorously tested theory of physics, the Standard Model. However, perturbation theory relies on the ability to modify known solutions by introducing small perturbations — thus reaching new solutions. These perturbations are proportional to the interaction strength (between the constituents) of the system. When the system's interaction strength is large, there is no small quantity with which to perturb the known solution by. And so the system is deemed non-perturbative — methods other than perturbation theory are necessary to explore the properties of the system. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If I compile your example document, the spacing looks fine. Please make sure that the example reproduces the issue.

Comment: I do not get that look either using TeXLive 2019. Are you by any chance using MikTeX?

Comment: @daleif That does not matter - Lopye Tall will not get that output on a MikTeX system. At least, I do not. It is obviously some code he do not disclose. Probably a font that is not installed correctly, or substituted by another.

Comment: @Sveinung the font looks grainy to me, so could be the CM-super problem al over again.

Comment: I am also *unable* to reproduce the cramped look of your screenshot; I'm on a MacOS/MacTeX2019 system. Do please tell us more about the OS and the TeX distribution you employ.

Comment: hmmmm I'm using overleaf/shareLaTex, so I don't think my OS should matter? 2011 Mac, version 10.13.6

Comment: What exactly is MikTex?

Comment: MikTeX and TeXLive are TeX distributions that allow you to process LaTeX files locally. Since you are using overleaf it might make sense to contact their support staff. What you see is not normal behaviour.

Comment: Hmmm, if this helps, the same output is cramped via the TexShop app on a mac

Comment: Does it help if you add `\usepackage{lmodern}` to the preamble?

Comment: Your log file should show (the first line) what version of the TeX engine you're using, and also (near the end of the file) the fonts being used.  If you add this information to your question, it should give us a better clue about what is going on.